# Application is compiled but does not run

Tags: wpf, xbap

I made some changes in a WPF xBap application and it compiles well but the new changes is not applied and when I put a break-point on the changed lines, the IDE ignores the break-point and shoes the following hint message: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit, No executable code associated with this line."

I tried the following:

- Cleaned and Rebuilt the Solution
- Cleaned the cache
- Restart the machine

and no hope.

Any idea or suggestion will be appreciated.

**Note**: The application works well with the new changes in the published version but it does not through the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

"No executable code associated with this line"

try to add a debug line `Console.WriteLine()` and add a break point at that line.

Comment: It's a WPF application not console.

Comment: You can refer to console in WPF application. It will ÏIRC write to the debug window in VS.

Comment: even it is not console, you can still write that code and compile. that code is just for testing

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it's because a wrong path in the file `projectName.csproj.user`.

I opened the file using the notepad and edited it manually.